# How to add UIView on the top of all views

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

I'm trying to set a subview on my application for all views, i want to use it for internet connection test.

I have tried  adding it to `UIWindow` in `appDelegate` 
using this code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let myNewView=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 300, height: 200))
    myNewView.backgroundColor=UIColor.red
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(myNewView)
}
```

when i run my app i don't find any changes , and the subview doesn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becasuse in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` this

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?
```

is `nil` you can use

```
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
self.window?.addSubview(.....
```

After you init with correct window or guarantee a root vc from IB with storyboard entry